# UIImageView display in front of navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uinavigationbar

Is there any way to display an image infront of the navigation bar?

I know this is a little bit messy - but its just an asthetic thing. The imageview takes up more height than the view and therefore needs to overlap the navigation bar a little bit.

Is this possible at all? It must be. :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, just have the image on a view that is on top of the navigation controller view and you can put it wherever you like.  It is however probably aesthetically unpleasing, and more likely than not frowned upon by the Apple Human Interface Guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

If your content is big enough that you need the space where the nav bar is, but you still need the nav bar to be present, how about making it transparent? (See, for example, the built-in Photos app.)

But, in general, UIKit views don't clip their contents. So if your view draws outside of its bounds, that will layer on to of whatever views are below it.

Comment: good idea, but not what I was looking for. I want it so that I can get the kinda effect you get when newspapers cut around the top of a picture so some of it spills out of the bounds... :) +1 for the idea though. :)